# Implementação de Pilha em C, como passar valores?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Estou tentando fazer a implementação de uma pilha em C. O solicitado pelo professor já está basicamente feito que era mostrar um erro caso a pilha estivesse cheia ou vazia. Porém ao ir para main eu encontrei grande dificuldade.

```
//
//  Trabalho Prático 1.c
//  IFTM
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 4/26/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_ELEMENTOS 5

typedef struct {
    //Vetor onde os dados serão armazenados posteriormente
    int elementos[MAX_ELEMENTOS];
    //Posição na pilha e quantidade de elementos
    int topo;
} pilha;

pilha * cria_pilha(){
    pilha *pi;
    pi = malloc(sizeof(pilha));

    if (!pi) {
        pi -> topo = 0;
    }
    return pi;

}

int empilha(pilha *pi, int p);
int desempilha(pilha *pi);
int tamanho (pilha *pi);
void destroi(pilha *pi);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
    //Ponteiro para pi para pilha, sempre que for usar no main
    //Criando a pilha atribuindo ao ponteiro pi a chamada de função cria_pilha();
    pilha *pi = cria_pilha();
    //Cria vetor de struct preenchido com a quantidade MAX_ELEMENTOS
    pilha infos[MAX_ELEMENTOS] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        empilha(pi, infos[i]);
    }
}

int empilha(pilha *pi, int p){
    if (pi == NULL || pi -> elementos == ((int*)MAX_ELEMENTOS)) {
        printf("Erro, pilha cheia.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pi -> elementos[pi->topo] = p;
    pi -> topo = pi -> topo + 1;
    return 1;
}

int desempilha(pilha *pi){
    if (pi == NULL || pi -> elementos[0] == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    pi -> topo = pi -> topo -1;
    return pi -> elementos[pi->topo];
}

int tamanho(pilha *pi){
    return pi -> topo;
}

void destroi(pilha *pi){
    free(pi);
}
```

Eu criei o for dentro da main para chamar a função de preenchimento MAX_ELEMENTOS vezes e colocar os valores do vetor dentro da pilha. Porém no for estou recebendo este erro... Passing 'pilha' to parameter of incompatible type 'int'

Eu identifiquei, o erro a função empilha, o segundo argumento está como inteiro. E quando chamo a função na main, estou passando o ponteiro da criação da pilha e um vetor infos do tipo pilha e não int. Porém eu criei o vetor como tipo pilha pelo falo da struct do código estar sendo declarada como typedef struct pilha que é um requisito também... Como posso trabalhar com esse vetor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá fiz uma pequena correção, com essa alteração será passado como argumento um valor int da array **elementos**, presente na struct **info** do tipo **pilha**, ao invés da struct **info** em si,

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        empilha(pi, infos -> elementos[i]);
    }
```

Adicionei esta parte para testar se a pilha havia sido preenchida com sucesso

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        printf("%d", pi -> elementos[i]);
}
```